# Visual Studio 2008 grouping and subsummary

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to add in my report a subsummary which shows the SUM of values for a group.  Is there a way to do this using expressions? I know this is not coded correctly, but to better explain:
=SUM (Fields!check_amount.value, "dataset1") Groupby (Fields!group_number.value, "dataset1")
The returned SUM will be shown below the last item that is in that group_number.value.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It needed to be put into the syntax and then the field used as an expression.

SELECT
         .source_cde,
         .trans_desc,
         .trans_amt,
         .trans_dte,
         .payable_check_dte,
         .check_num_num,
         .group_num,
         .acct_cde,
         SUM (trans_amt) sum_amount

FROM *

WHERE         (.source_cde IN (@SourceCode)) AND
                 (.acct_cde IN (@AccountCode)) AND
                 (.payable_check_dte is Null) AND
                 (.trans_dte BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd)

GROUP BY 
         Group_num, source_cde, trans_desc, trans_amt, trans_dte, payable_check_dte, check_num_num, acct_cde

Then in the table itself call on =Sum(Fields!sum_amount.Value)

Thanks to anyone looking into it.